# Распаковка списков и словарей в строку

Tags: python

есть такой простой пример

```
def test(x, y, z):
    print(x, y, z)

l = [1, 2, 3]
d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}

print(*l)
print(*d)
```

тут все распаковывается на ура, но если попробовать получить значение из словаря

```
print(**d)
```

уже не пашет

Comment: Какой конкретно вывод вы ожидаете?

Comment: Две звёздочки не распаковывают значения, а передают словарь, как именованные аргументы. Но функций `print` не имеет именованных аргументов x. y и z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте распаковать `d.values()`

```
print(*d.values())
```

Comment: Благодарю, так пашет

Comment: @Vadim, если вам нужны и ключи и значения, то можно так: `print(*d.items())`